# Can I declare an "alias" function which checks an object's type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, declaration

I'm working on converting a codebase to TypeScript and it has a lot of shorthand functions like `isFunction`, `isArray`, and `isString`. Is there a way for me to declare to the TypeScript interpreter what these shorthand functions do (e.g. declare that `isFunction(x)` is exactly the same as `typeof x === 'function'`), so we can continue to use these shorthands?

```
function isFunction (x) {
    return typeof x === 'function';
}
function isArray (x) {
    return x instanceof Array;
}
function isString (x) {
    return (typeof x === 'string');
}
```

As currently written, TS only knows that `isFunction(x)` returns a boolean, so it has no way of knowing that `isFunction(x)` is exactly the same as `typeof x === 'function'`, so it throws a compile-time error when I attempt to do this.

```
function doCallback(callback?: () => {}) {
    if (typeof callback === 'function')
        callback(); // Allowed by TS interpreter
}
function doCallback(callback?: () => {}) {
    if (isFunction(callback))
        callback(); // Error: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
}
```

Comment: [Type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @caTS pointed out, the solution is [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```
function isFunction (x): x is Function {
    return typeof x === 'function';
}
function isArray (x): x is Array<any> {
    return Array.isArray(x);
}
function isString (x): x is string {
    return (typeof x === 'string');
}
```

Comment: I'd use `Array.isArray` instead - it's built-in and also the canonical way to check if something is an array-like anyways.